# Why does quicksort take longer when sorted in descending order vs ascending order

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have code for quicksort and mergesort, and I've placed a global counter variable that gets incremented for every iteration(comparison) that is made.  I would assume this would correspond to my rough asymptotic analysis.  For merge sort it does, but for quicksort it doesn't.  I don't understand why.  I'm choosing the last element of the input array is the pivot in every iteration.  I know that this is non-optimal, but that doesn't matter for the sake of this discussion.  Since I'm choosing the last element, I would expect that both ascending and descending order arrays would result in O(n^2) comparisons.  To be more specific, I would expect that the number of comparisons would be n choose 2, because you are adding n + n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + .... + 1 in the worst case.  But this does not seem to be happening.

On an input size of 100,000, with the input sorted in descending order I get 705,082,704 iterations counted.  I get the same number for an input array sorted in ascending order. But 100,000 choose 2 is around 5 billion.  Why the discrepancy?

For merge sort, with an input of 100,000, I get approx 1.6 million iterations, which is seemingly correct.

The following is the code which includes my implementation of quicksort as well as my counting technique, both of which may be off and thus causing this discrepancy.  Otherwise it must be that my logic is wrong about how many iterations this should take?

Also, as an aside, its curious to me that although the number of comparisons are the same in both the ascending and descending input arrays, the ascending version is 2-3 times as fast.  What could account for that.  Without further ado here is the code.

```
int counter = 0;
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}


int partition(int *array, int low, int high){
  int firsthigh = low;
  int pivot = high;

  for(int i = low; i < high; i++)
  {
    counter++;
    if(array[i] < array[pivot])
    {
      swap(array[i], array[firsthigh]);
      firsthigh++;
    }
  }
  swap(array[pivot],array[firsthigh]);
  return firsthigh;
}

void quicksort(int *array, int low, int high){
  int p;
  if(low < high)
  {
    p = partition(array, low, high);
    quicksort(array, low, p-1);
    quicksort(array,p+1,high);
  }
}

int main(){
  int array[100000];
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    array[i] = i;

  struct timeval start, end;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

  //mergesort(array, 0, 99999);
  quicksort(array, 0, 99999);

  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
  long long time =   (end.tv_sec * (unsigned int)1e6 +   end.tv_usec) -
                     (start.tv_sec * (unsigned int)1e6 + start.tv_usec);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;

  cout << endl << endl << time/1000000.0 << endl;
  cout << endl << counter;
}
```

Comment: By the way, don't get the start time before doing the output. It will skew the timing.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg why not? isn't the goal to benchmark the quicksort procedure and not the output?

Comment: Your quicksort is inefficient because you always pick `high` as your pivot (among other things). Try at least picking the pivot randomly.

Comment: @IVlad yes I know that is why it is inefficient. I'm wondering why in particular it is not iterating as much as I would expect it to.  Also, what are the other reasons the quicksort is inefficient, I'd be very curious to know

Comment: You should have your calls to `gettimeofday()` just before and just after the sort function calls. You are currently also measuring the time it takes to print the array.

Comment: You don't seem to be counting all the swaps. Shouldn't you have another `counter++` in `if(array[i] < array[pivot])`?

Comment: @IVlad I'm not sure.  My thinking was that by counting every iteration of the loop I was accounting for that in terms of big-O analysis.  i.e., the anything more would just be a constant factor, but the number of iterations of that for loop should be n-choose-2 in the worst case

Comment: In that case, it looks right to me. For `10000`, `counter` will be 10000*10001/2 = 50005000. I'm not patient enough to let it run for `100 000`, but I'm guessing you are overflowing an int and that's why your result is off. Use long long.

Comment: Don't use an int, you're probably overflowing. In fact, 0xFFFFFFFF + 705,082,704 is about 5 billions, the number you're expecting.

Comment: Since you are passing a `low` and `high` index to your sort function shouldn't the correct parameters be `quicksort(array, 0, 99999)` ?

Comment: yes.  another big mistake.  It was initially but I was switching it around and made that error.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you want to count the number of iterations of the inner for loop, use `long long`. `n*(n-1)/2` overflows an int for `n = 100 000`. If you want to count swaps, you should increment your counter whenever a swap is being done.
2. Two easy optimizations to make to this are:

   - pick the pivot randomly;
   - make the partitioning function more efficient by using Hoare partitioning: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/quicksort-partitioning-hoare-vs-lomuto

There are others of course, but this should get you a decent algorithm.

Comment: When you say pick the pivot randomly do you mean using a PRNG library function to pick the pivot? I've read this adds a lot of overhead.  I've also read that you should take the first, middle, and last element and find the median, and that should be your pivot.  Does that hold any water?

Comment: @ordinary: median-of-3 and median-of-5 are ways to get a "relatively" good pivot, unfortunately it can be attacked by building an adversary input that specifically make you pick bad values for your algorithm (since they are deterministic). A PRNG protects you from arbitrary inputs, and it is then a matter of choosing between a really good randomness (cryptographic quality ?) or just some randomness... there are many PRNG with various randomness/performance profiles.

Comment: @ordinary Yes, I mean using a PRNG. Obviously it adds **some** overhead, but I wouldn't say it's a lot. It's definitely much faster than any `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: Or, instead of a random pivot, you can start off with a single [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) at the very beginning of the sort.